# Can I connect ADF V1 Self Hosted IR in ADF V2?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have some pipelines running in ADF V1, I want to run one more pipeline which involves AWS Redshift as a source, and it needs a Self hosted IR to do that, currently we dont have any option to specify the IR in AWS Redshift connection, so am wondering how this can be done if I Can connect the ADF V1 IR to ADF V2?

Answer (score 0):

Currently we cannot reuse the ADF V1 self-hosted IR in ADF V2. You may need to create a new self-hosted IR in ADF V2, then select this IR in "Connect via integration runtime" property.